# Does the AWS Glue job bookmark get overwritten if a new Deployment for the same Glue job is done ,?

Tags: aws-glue

We ae debating whether to use Glue bookmarking for reading off daily incremental data from a S3 location.
We are not sure if a new Glue job deployment is done , would it overwrite the existing bookmarks ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it does not. I frequently update my Glue Jobs and the bookmarks still work as expected.

I couldn't find anything in the Glue documentation regarding this though, so you would have to contact the Glue Team via the AWS support to get full confidence.